# Can we publish a message without key and header in kafka topics

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to write kafka producer to publish my data in avro without using using any key or header. If i publish message without key or header can consumer read the message from topics? Please help to understand how do consume message if key and header not exists

I have tried without header and key to publish avro record but consumer asking me to publish with key . Is there any possible to read topics and messages from topics ?

Comment: Hi @Viswesh, could you publish your code please.
 Key & headers are not mandatory in Kafka, but keys allows you to garantee that messages with same keys will be in the same partition => so they'll be processed in order

Comment: What consumer library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Key and headers are completely optional. Serialization format doesn't matter. Producers and consumers don't communicate with one another, so it is unclear who/what is "asking to publish with key"